# "Not enough space in Runtime area!!. SMBIOS data will not be available."

Tags: boot, bios

I have a user with a Dell Vostro 220 that will not boot.  It posts, then give the following error:

> Not enough space in Runtime area!!.  SMBIOS data will not be available.

I Googled the error and there is remarkable little out there.  There are a few other Vostro owners with this error, as well as a few other people.  Most of the threads point back to one article, but I tried the suggestions of pulling the CMOS battery and holding cntrl-pgup.  Neither worked.  I reset BIOS to recommended settings, which didnt work.  The BIOS is rather sparse, so there is nothing else that is visible to clear.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems like it might be a BIOS address space issue.  Pull all non essential devices from the computer (just leave PSU, MB, CPU, a single RAM stick, and video) and see if you get the same error.  Also, have you tried (re)flashing the BIOS with the latest version yet?  If you're not aware then FYI (might help in your search) the SMBIOS is the "System Management BIOS" which is the sub-system that can be used to interface motherboard/BIOS elements like fan speeds, temperatures, chassis conditions, etc. with the OS via a driver.

Comment: Flash the bios/uefi, if that is not possilble get bios chip and toss it in.  those are the solutions seen on the web. I would say check the ram , and connections to cpu (on modern on die ram controller cpus) also.

Comment: The computer wont boot, so I cant flash the BIOS.  I tried replacing the RAM, no good.  I think it is a lost cause.

Comment: There exists desktops in existance that have flashing capability without init (even) and ones that will flash (asus) without a CPU , which amazed me how that is even possible.  then we got this dell :-)  which has (as far as i can tell) a top soldered bios chip , not socketed, possible to replace, if one Knew that would fix it.

Comment: @Psycogeek true, but this machine is ancient.  I gave up on it and just removed the drive and copied his data.  The machine is off to be recycled.